# Apply style to the first element of a dynamic list

Tags: html, css

I have a list that is generated from the database so I don't have a specific lenght and I don't have html code of each row..
But I need to set a particular style to the first row of the list. 
So I ask if is it possible to tell to css to apply a style only to the first element, also if the list is dynamic.

```
<tr>
   <td class="align-center"><? echo $myvariable; ?></td>
</tr>
```

If this TD is generated for example 40 times, only the first must have a certain style. It's possible? 
Thanks in advice.

Comment: Please check [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to target first `tr` then use

```
table tr:first-child {
    /* Styles goes here */
}
```

And if you want to target first `td` of first `tr` then use

```
table tr:first-child td:first-child {
    /* Styles goes here */
}
```

And if you want to target first `td` of every `tr`

```
table tr td:first-child {
    /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Just to make sure that you target the right `table`, atleast provide a `class` or an `id` to that `table` and use it in your selector.